# Using EditTextPreference with 2 user input fields

Tags: android

I would like to use EditTextPreference to show 2 input fields instead of 1. For instance, a username and password field should be shown. I don't want to use a dialog for each one. How can this be done? In the WiFi settings there is one that does this, when you want connect to a  protected network, a dialog shows to set a password for the credential storage with 2 fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`DialogPreference`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) and create your own layout for the input fields you require.

`DialogPreference` is `abstract` so you'll need to create your own subclass of it, adding an implementation of [`onDialogClosed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onDialogClosed(boolean)) to save the values from the dialog as Preferences.

You can still reference your own class in a Preferences XML file by using the class as the XML tag.  For example:

```
<com.yourdomain.YourDialogPreference
    android:title="Title"
    android:summary="Summary"
    android:key="dialog_preference"/>
```