# How to make a custom Dialog Preference inside Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, listpreference, dialog-preference

I searched all Around this forum , but not getting what i exactly need. I need a Custom DialogPreference in Preference but that DialogPreference shouldn't have blue-strip header which i hate, And i already prepared one activity header template xml file for other activities which can be used as custom activity header.so i want to use that on this dialogPrerence. Plus i want Custom Preference File name but here the problem is it creates two Preference File name, one for Preference and Another for DialogPreference

but i found something like this here [Using EditTextPreference with 2 user input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192965/using-edittextpreference-with-2-user-input-fields)

```
    <com.yourdomain.YourDialogPreference
        android:title="Title"
        android:summary="Summary"
        android:key="dialog_preference"/>
```

i 've done so far with this. DialogPreference Opens well, but how can i attach my header template to this custom DialogPreference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my self. Here you go.

1st include following line for the Header Template in the DialogPreference XML

```
<include layout="@layout/activity_header_template" />
```

and prepare own custom dialog layout just like normal custom dialog Template. The real need is, i want to customize the DialogPreference, I want two inputs for Password 1 and Password 2. (just to confirm the password)

This is my ListPreference XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/preference_header_encryption">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="prefkey_use_passcode"
            android:title="@string/preference_name_set_passcode"
            android:summary="@string/preference_summary_set_passcode" />

        <!-- This is how you need to attach CustomDialogPrefernce, by using the class name -->
        <!-- Please ignore title here. Title will come from DialogPreference Constructor --> 
        <com.nerds.notes.SettPassword
            android:key="prefkey_set_passcode"
            android:summary="@string/preference_app_protection"
            android:dialogMessage="@string/action_delete"
            android:positiveButtonText="@string/passcode_ok_button_text"
            android:negativeButtonText="@string/passcode_cancel_button_text"
            android:dependency="prefkey_use_passcode" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="prefkey_app_protection"
            android:title="@string/preference_app_protection"
            android:summary="@string/preference_summary_app_protection"
            android:dependency="prefkey_use_passcode" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Following lines are very Important, the DialogPreference Constructor

```
public SettPassword(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setPersistent(false);
    setTitle(R.string.preference_name_set_passcode); // This will override ListPreference Title
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.passcode_set_dialog_template);
}
```

Following lines should be coded in the ListPreference OnCreate Method to have custom Preference File name

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
    manager.setSharedPreferencesName("Your Preference File Name");
    manager.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_PRIVATE);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings); // ListPreference XML file from XML Folder
}
```

Comment: Some methods here i used are depreciated